# python find digits string in line

Tags: python, regex, string, match, digits

I have this kind of long log file.

```
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass6 [INFO] everything normal for id 174025851
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass4 [FATAL] system problem at id 1991740254
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 1304807656
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
```

I want to find `id=1740` exactly, and print line, but `id=174025851` also count in it. how can I find exactly string `id=1740` in a line and print line.

```
for line in f: 
    if str(id) in line: 
        print(line)
```

it also print the first and second line but I just want 4th line only with exactly id 1740

Comment: If you mean **exactly** then line.strip().endsWith(“id 1740”) or something similar? (Not at a machine to test this atm.)

Comment: if you're using the `re` module  then wouldn't `re.search(r'\b1740\b',line)` suffice?

Comment: Zaman Azam: I updated my answer to reflect what you wrote under pciunkiewicz's answer regarding the fact that the "id" could occur in the _middle_ of the string as well as the end. This detail should have been stated up front in the question, because not knowing it invalidates a number of answers. Please can you edit your question now to reflect the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

At risk of adding yet another answer to a question which has many already, here is how I think that a regular expression parser is best used here:

```
import re

the_id = 1740

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search("id\s+(\d+)\s*$", line)
        if match and the_id == int(match.group(1)):
            print(line, end='')
```

This gives:

```
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
```

What you are doing here is using the parser to look for lines which end with the following: "id", followed by whitespace, followed by one or more digits (which you capture in a group), optionally followed by any amount of whitespace.

The captured group is then converted to int and compared with the id.

Incidentally, the id is stored in variable called `the_id`, because `id` is the name of a builtin function so is not a good choice of variable name (interferes with use of the builtin).

---

## UPDATE

The asker has now clarified that the ID can appear in the middle of the line, not necessarily at the end.

This can easily be handled by a simple tweak to the regular expression.  Changing the relevant line in the above code to:

```
        match = re.search("id\s+(\d+)", line)
```

now removes any check on what should come *after* the digits.

Because the `+` meaning "one or more" is also *greedy* (that is, it matches the part of the pattern to which it relates *as many times as possible*), the *whole* of the ID is matched by the bracketed group, without need to specify anything about what follows it.

Given the input file

```
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass6 [INFO] everything normal for id 174025851
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass4 [FATAL] system problem at id 1991740254
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 1304807656
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
2012-02-03 19:11:02 id 1740 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail
```

this will now output:

```
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
2012-02-03 19:11:02 id 1740 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail
```

Comment: is this also wor on this line

Comment: Feb 23 07:38:19 router1 snmpd[359]: SNMPD_TRAP_COLD_START: trap_generate_cold: SNMP 1740 trap: cold start

Comment: @ZamanAzam That does not even contain the string `id`. How is the code supposed to know that that is an id?

Comment: So I have different log files. Which I filter using .log. Then I read first file. And every line in file contains different number strings. The number(Id) is given by user. If it’s exactly same in the line. Then it print line

Comment: snmpd[359]: SNMPD_TRAP_WARM_START:SNMP trap: warm start
SNMPD_THROTTLE_QUEUE_DRAINED:() cleared all throttled traps
SNMPD_TRAP_WARM_START:SNMP trap:(1740;543;544) warm start
SNMPD_TRAP_COLD_START:SNMP trap:(1740737)cold start

Comment: in this case 3rd line online print as it contains

Comment: 1740 exactly. but fourth line contains different @alaniwi

Comment: @ZamanAzam Yes I see that, but this was not clear previously. The code would then have to be a bit different because you have to use `re.findall` - the previous assumption was that there was _one_ thing on each line which could be the ID, from what you are saying now, you would have to pull out all of the numbers because you do not know whether 1740 or 543 or 544 is the ID. At this stage, I do not propose to edit the code any further. Another time, please ensure that the question explains everything from the start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this and split the line and take the last value:

```
for line in f: 
    if '1740' in line:
        a = line.split(' ')[-1]
        if a == '1740': 
            print(line)
```

Comment: I don't think want you to hard-code the value `'1740'` (especially not having the same constant hard-coded in two places), but you might want to take the opportunity to suggest a better variable name for it than the `id` used in the question (which is the name of a builtin).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the structure of your logs, if the id is always at the very end of the line you can always change it to look for lines ending with your exact query:

```py
for line in f: 
    if line.endswith(f"id {id}"): 
        print(line)
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned by @mrblewog, if the line has trailing whitespace, we can pre-process it using `rstrip` or `strip`:

```py
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    ### Rest of the logic ###
```

Comment: Potentially need to strip whitespace off the line before endswith

Comment: what if the line id to search for is 1740 but the line ends with 1991740? This wouldn't work.

Comment: @DavidErickson Ahh yeah you're right! I have updated it to be more precise, starting all the way back from `id XXXXXXXX`.

Comment: id can also appear in middle, its a long log file

Comment: 2012-02-03 19:11:02 id 1740 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail

Comment: @ZamanAzam The fact that it can be in the middle is an important detail, which should be given in the question, not hidden away in the comments below one of the answers. Is there always only one id per line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex something like id followed by space.
Or if the id is always at the end of the line. Then use
If line.endswith('id '+id) is true then do your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with regex as -

```
import re
file = ['2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass6 [INFO] everything normal for id 174025851',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass4 [FATAL] system problem at id 1991740254',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 1304807656',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740']
for line in file :
    num = re.findall(r'\d+', line)[-1]
    if(num == '1740'):
        print(line)
```

**Output :**

```
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
```

With this code, you will find the last number that occurs on each line even if the string is not ending with a number.

---

The following will check if `1740` occurs anywhere in the line.

```
import re
file = ['2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass6 [INFO] everything normal for id 174025851',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass4 [FATAL] system problem at id 1991740254',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 1304807656',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740',
'2012-02-03 19:11:02 id 1740 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail ']
for line in file :
    num = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
    if('1740' in num):
        print(line)
```

---

Or if you are sure that each line ends with a number then you can simple split the string and compare with the last element of the split as -

```
file = ['2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass6 [INFO] everything normal for id 174025851',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass4 [FATAL] system problem at id 1991740254',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 1304807656',
'2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740']

for line in file :
    num = line.split()[-1]
    if(num == '1740'):
        print(line)
```

**Output :**

```
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
```

Comment: id can be anywhere in file. like in middle of strin line.

Comment: Then the regex code would work for you(provided its the last number that occurs on that line)

Comment: like id can appears like this in file,

Comment: 2012-02-03 19:11:02 id 1740 SampleClass5 [TRACE] verbose detail

Comment: @ZamanAzam See if the second one that I added now helps. It works for the case you provided

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

```
import re
text = """
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass6 [INFO] everything normal for id 174025851
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass4 [FATAL] system problem at id 1991740254
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [DEBUG] detail for id 1304807656
2012-02-03 18:35:34 SampleClass3 [WARN] missing id 1740
"""

# the \s means the char after 0 must be a space, tab or newline (so, not a number)
p = re.compile(r'.*id 1740\s') 
ls = p.findall(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_csv('/path/to/data.txt', header=None)

for i in range(0,len(data)):
    if data.iloc[i,0].split(' ')[-1][:4]=='1740':
        print(data.iloc[i,0])
```

I use csv even if not comma-separated so that I keep lines as single strings! Then check within a loop.